# Using jQuery and JSON to plot Google map v3 markers, Rails

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to plot an array of maps markers that are returned in JSON format from a jQuery request.

However the maps load but the markers do not, here is my .js file:

```
//gmaps.js
function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.1526, -2.110)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);



  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/getrws',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).success(function(rws) {

    rws.forEach(function(rw) {

      rwMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(rw.latitude, rw.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "hello",
        icon: '/images/closedroad.png'
      })
    })
  });

}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
    '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

The gmaps.js is called from my maps.html.erb partial as follows

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps.js" %>
<% end %>

<div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script>initialize();</script>
</div>
```

and my ajax portion of my routes looks like this:

```
  class OnlyAjaxRequests
    def matches?(request)
      request.xhr?
    end
  end

 match '/ajax/getrws' => 'roadworks#rtrnjsonroadworks', :constraints => OnlyAjaxRequests.new, via: :post, defaults: {format: 'json'}
```

Comment: What does `rw.latitude` and `rw.longitude` look like?  Are they strings by any chance?  If so, wrap them in `parseFloat()` before passing them to the LatLng constructor.

Comment: @duncan you are correct in that they are strings, however wrapping them as follows doesn't seem to work; `position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(rw.latitude),parseFloat(rw.longitude))`

Comment: The ajax request is successful? The forEach loop correctly iterates over all the roadworks?

Comment: You're calling initialise twice I think. Once from `<script>initialize();</script>` and once via the callback which you specify via the loadScript function

Comment: The ajax request seems to be successful and it loops over each element correctly. Might be the way the map is being loaded as you were saying, without the `<script>initialize();</script>` in the view the mpa only loads once the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Rookie error, the map marker icon was not placed in the public directory, so the maps api could not access it.